# CakePHP 3.5.2 auto deleted index.php file from webroot why?

Tags: cakephp

i use command : "cake server" to start the project.

It run the first time. The second time it give me this error

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 
‘C:\Users\duyqu\Desktop\page\webroot/index.php’ (include_path=’.;C:\php\pear’) in Unknown on line 0
```

I have check several time and it appear to delete the “index.php” file in webroot folder for no reason.

Here is what is already try:

-re-download Wamp server and composer

-update to newest version 3.5.2 of cakePHP

-copy the index.php to another place and recopy them back to webroot ( can’t be done because access denied)

I am stuck and have no idea what is happening. I have been use cakePHP for 6 months and this is the first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it could be antivirus. Everytime I create new project - everytime my antivirus tries to delete `webroot/index.php`

Comment: OMG you save my live. Thank you alot. It is avast delete that file, i found all the file in virus chest.